# how to move elements around web page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created three shapes(circles) on my webpage that are positioned in the background of other elements on the page using z-index in CSS and the position is absolute.

I'm trying to move them around my page as soon as my page loads.

The following is the code I wrote attempting to do the above. I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong. Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  $("shape-1").animate({
    "margin-top": "+= 200px"
  }, 2000);
  $("shape-2").animate({
    "margin-right": "+= 200px"
  }, 2000);
  $("shape-3").animate({
    "margin-bottom": "+= 200px"
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.shape-1,
.shape-2,
.shape-3 {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(197, 96, 223, 0.904), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37));
  z-index: 1;
}

.shape-1 {
  top: 1%;
  left: 13%;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
.shape-2 {
  top: 21%;
  right: 17%;
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
}
.shape-3 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape-1"></div>
<div class="shape-2"></div>
<div class="shape-3"></div>
```

Comment: Typo. The selectors are missing the class prefix, eg. `$('shape-1')` needs to be `$('.shape-1')`, and the values needs to not have the space in them to be recognised as an incremental operation: `"+=200px"`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mqjexapd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to select the elements with a proper CSS selector. `$("shape-1")` does not select anything. `$(".shape-1")` does.
- You need to animate the properties that determine the position of the element. Animating `margin-bottom` will do nothing for you. The elements are pinned into place by `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`. You need to animate those.
- You need to decide whether you want to use percentages (as your CSS defines) or pixels (as your JS code attempts) to position an element. You can't combine both.
- You need to animate percentages as absolute values, you can't do `+= 50%`. You can animate an element from its original absolute position (e.g. `1%`) to a new absolute position (e.g. `50%`).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".shape-1").animate({top: "50%", left: "50%"}, 2000);
  $(".shape-2").animate({right: "50%"}, 2000);
  $(".shape-3").animate({bottom: "10%"}, 2000);
});
```

```css
.shape-1,
.shape-2,
.shape-3 {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(197, 96, 223, 0.904), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37));
  z-index: 1;
}
.shape-1 {
  top: 1%;
  left: 13%;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
.shape-2 {
  top: 21%;
  right: 17%;
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
}
.shape-3 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape-1"></div>
<div class="shape-2"></div>
<div class="shape-3"></div>
```